# JSON request returns a blank response randomly causing script to fail

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a python script that is failing when my request returns a blank JSON response.  The code loops through the function repeatedly and is successful 99% of the time, but fails every once in a while when a blank JSON response is received.

```
i = 0
while i < 1000:
r = 0
while r < 4:
    time.sleep(5)
    response = c.get_quote(symbol)
    jsonData = response.json()
    for key in jsonData:        
        jsonkey = key
    if jsonkey == symbol:
        print (i)
        print("you are good", response)
        print(jsonData)
        print ()
        break
    else:
        print("you have a problem, jsonkey=")
        print()
        print (jsonData)
        print()
    r =+ 1
current_price = response.json()[symbol]["lastPrice"]
i += 1
```

The 'While r < 4:' loop was added in an attempt to add error handling.  If I can figure out what to trap on, I would retry the `response = c.get_quote(symbol)`  but the blank JSON response is slipping past the `if jsonkey == symbol` logic.

The error message received is "current_price = response.json()[symbol]["lastPrice"]
KeyError: 'NVCR'"

and the output from print (jsonData) is: {}
as opposed to a healthy response which contains the symbol as a key with additional data to follow.  The request is returning a response [200] so unfortunately it isn't that simple...

Comment: Unrelated, but what exactly is the point of `for key in jsonData: jsonkey = key` ?

Comment: Seeing that a request is sent every 5 seconds the cause is likely to be some kind of throttling done by the server. Your code should (as always) check for errors

Comment: @DeepSpace the JSON response only has one index where the key should be the symbol I am passing in the request.  I am learning Python and have only been at it for a few weeks, it was the only way I could figure out how to get the key name from a JSON response.  If there is a better way, I would love to learn.

Comment: @DeepSpace The API can be called 120 times per minute.  That was my first thought, but it is not the case.  I removed the time.wait and it starts returning a specific response that I have exceeded the threshold, not a blank response.

This is an excerpt of code I am using for testing from a much larger program that I am running in a different script.  In that program, this code runs once per minute.  Some days I can run 7 hours without a failure or get a failure every hour or two.

Comment: Now, for the actual error, which module are you using? Is it the json module or something else?

Comment: @CarlHR But *why* though? Just directly access the key... `jsonData[symbol]`

Comment: I mean, when you call `response.json()`. The variable `response` is an object created by which python module?

Comment: Well, we can't fix the *server*. We can fix your code to not crash when the server returns a malformed response.

Comment: @CarlHR That does not matter. OP just need to use `.get` or `try-except KeyError`

Comment: You should be validating that `r.status_code == 200` regardless, as well as handling the KeyError like DeepSpace noted

Comment: @CarlHR yes I am using the json module

Comment: @Chris the response does return a 200 status code... that was one of my first tests, but for whatever reason it wasn't that simple.

Comment: Anyways, as @DeepSpace mentioned, use a `try-except KeyError` on your script when trying to access the `symbol` key in `jsonData`. If it doesn't work, the script will throw an exception and continue executing instead of exiting on error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating the key with `jsonkey == symbol`, use a [`try-except`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) block to catch the blank response errors and handle them.

For instance:

```
i = 0
while i < 1000:

time.sleep(5)
response = c.get_quote(symbol)
jsonData = response.json()
try:
    for key in jsonData:        
        jsonkey = key
    if jsonkey == symbol:
        print (i)
        print("you are good", response)
        print(jsonData + "\n")
        break
except:
    print("you have a problem \n")
    print (jsonData + "\n")

current_price = response.json()[symbol]["lastPrice"]
i += 1
```

@DeepSpace is also likely correct in the comments. My guess is that the server that you're pulling json data from ([nsetools?](https://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)) is throttling your requests, so it might be worth looking deeper in their docs to see if you can find a limit, and then use `time.sleep()` to stay under it.

Edit: If you are using [nsetools](https://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), their api seems to be built by reverse-engineering the api that the [nse website](https://www.nseindia.com/) is built on and performing json api calls to [urls such as this one](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/json/mostActiveMonthly.json) (these can be found in [this source code file](https://github.com/vsjha18/nsetools/blob/master/nse.py)). Because of this, it's not documented what the rate limit is, as this data is scraped directly from NSE and subject to their rate limit. Using this data is against NSE's terms of use (unless they have express written consent from the government of India which for all I know nsetools has, but I assume you do not.)

Comment: for some reason the "if jsonkey == symbol" evaluation returns as true even when the JSON response is blank...

I think that the try-except KeyError is the right way to go, but I am trying to figure out how to wrap retry logic around that.  

...
    try:

Comment: for reasons I don't understand, the if jsonkey == symbol returns as true even when the JSON response is blank, so this won't work...  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

OK so thanks to @DeepSpace and @CarlHR I think I have a solution but it still seems like there is too much code for what I am trying to accomplish.  This works:

```
i = 0
while i < 1000:
r = 1
while r < 5:
    time.sleep(1)
    response = c.get_quote(symbol)
    jsonData = response.json()
    try:
        current_price = response.json()[symbol]["lastPrice"]
        print ("Looks Good, moving on")
        break
    except KeyError:
        print ("There was an problem with the JSON response, 
        trying again.  retry number:", r)
        print (jsonData)
        print ()
        r += 1
     
i += 1
print ("Moving on to the next iteration")
```